# como puedo detectar la tecla delete en un datagrid c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

> ### **Hola buenas como puedo detectar la tecla delete (supr) en un datagrid en c#**

Answer (score 3):

Añade un evento KeyDown a tu grilla y tu codigo debe verse asi :

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("delete pressed");
       e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```